# enable and disable jquery draggable containment on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

i have created an jquery draggable example,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
.container{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#draggable{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
  </style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    containment: ".container"
        });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>
</div>
<input type= "button" value="toggle containment" id="buttonContain">
</body>
</html>
```

### in which, can i remove jquery draggable containment option after adding jquery drggable widget?  plz help

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 $("#draggable").draggable('disable');
```

for disable and

```
$("#draggable").draggable('enable');
```

for enable on button click

Comment: thanks for your answer @Sanyami Vaidya,  but i want to toggle draggable's containment option on click of button